# How to get user input for multiline lines in Python 3?

Tags: python, input, multiline

I know that the regular input function can accept single lines, but as soon as you try to write a string paragraph and hit enter for the next line, it terminates. Is there a beginner-friendly way to accept multiline user string inputs as variables?

Answer (score 3):

A common way of doing this in programs is to have an "I'm done" string (e.g. a single period), and to keep reading in lines until the line read matches that string.

```
print("Enter as many lines of text as you want.")
print("When you're done, enter a single period on a line by itself.")

buffer = []
while True:
    print("> ", end="")
    line = input()
    if line == ".":
        break
    buffer.append(line)
multiline_string = "\n".join(buffer)

print("You entered...")
print()
print(multiline_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using sys library

```
import sys
x = sys.stdin.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def processString(x):
    print(x.replace('process','whatever'))

lines = ""
while True:
    if lines == "":
        lines = ""
        print("Enter string:")
    x = input()
    if x == "" and lines != "":
        processString(lines)
        break
    else:
        lines += x

# then hit enter once after multi-line string to process it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
s = sys.stdin.read()
# print(s) # It will print everything 
for line in s.splitlines(): # to read line by line
    print(line)
```

Comment: While this may address the issue, you also want to provide a way to get out of the loop. Otherwise, this will be an endless multiline user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
[input() for i in range(int(input()))]
```

for n multiline user inputs, each index in the list will be a new line input from the user.

Answer (score -2):

```
Line=""

while True:

    x=input()

    Line=Line+" "+x

    if "." in x:

        break

print(Line)
```

Comment: `Line=Line+" "+x` is inefficient in Python, it's better to use `join`. Also, this would stop as soon as a line contains a dot, which could appear in many situations (Well... 3.14?). Finally, it removes the newlines between the inputs...